# MariaDB could not add nodes to cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera

could someone know how to solve below issue ?

i have allow all user to all member node

- all node can communication as well with port 3306

the issue as below :

```
WSREP: GCache history reset: 39163b37-81b8-11ed-8d9f-16421e0c684f:0 -> 39163b37-81b8-11ed-8d9f-16421e0c684f:2969752
Nov 22 00:42:20 SERVER-DB03 mariadbd[333037]: 2023-11-22  0:42:20 0 [Warning] WSREP: 1.0 (SERVER-DB01): State transfer to 0.0 (SERVER-DB03) failed: -113 (No route to host)
Nov 22 00:42:20 SRV-MV-DB03 mariadbd[333037]: 2023-11-22  0:42:20 0 [ERROR] WSREP: ./gcs/src/gcs_group.cpp:gcs_group_handle_join_msg():1207: Will never receive state. Need to abort.


mariadbd[333047]: Terminated
mariadbd[333047]: WSREP_SST: [INFO] Joiner cleanup: rsync PID=333173, stunnel PID=0 (20231122 00:42:20.510)
mariadbd[333047]: WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Cleanup after exit with status: 3 (20231122 00:42:20.505)
mariadbd[333047]: WSREP_SST: [INFO] Joiner cleanup done. (20231122 00:42:21.062)
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Try asking in dba StackExchange.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Your question seems more like a Mariadb cluster setup one.

Comment: Check the IP addresses and verify that the servers can find each other.

Comment: Dear Rick , Server can communication as well with database port 3306

Comment: does the servers have multiple IP addresses per node? maybe you will need to specify the listen and broadcast addresses in WSREP